# Multi JSON object into single JSON object

Tags: android, json

I have this schema for json object :

```
{
    "pRequest": {
        "ClsBuildingExeReport":{
            "BuildingExecRep_FormOperation_Main" : {
                "NIdBuildingExecRep" : "777"
            },
            "BuildingExecRep_Detail_Main": [
                {
                "BuildingExecDate": "2001/09/03",
                "BuildingExecTime": "11:13:17",
                "CI_ExecFloor": 0,
                "CI_ExecLevel": 9,
                },
                {
                "BuildingExecDate": "2001/09/03",
                "BuildingExecTime": "11:13:17",
                "CI_ExecFloor": 0,
                "CI_ExecLevel": 9,
                }...],
            "_NidProc": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        }
    }

}
```

I make `BuildingExecRep_FormOperation_Main` like this:

```
buildingExecRepFormOperationMain.put("NIdBuildingExecRep", nIdBuildingExecRep);
clsBuildingExeReport.put("BuildingExecRep_FormOperation_Main",
buildingExecRepFormOperationMain);    
clsBuildingExeReport2.put("ClsBuildingExeReport", clsBuildingExeReport);
```

In this way i added json object to `ClsBuildingExeReport` object.
Now I have created `BuildingExecRep_Detail_Main` How can i add this ArrayList into `ClsBuildingExeReport` object?

```
buildingExecRep_Detail_Main3.put("BuildingExecRep_Detail_Main", buildingExecRep_Detail_Main);
clsBuildingExeReport2.put("ClsBuildingExeReport", buildingExecRep_Detail_Main3);
```

When i execute this code `ClsBuildingExeReport` just has one of this object and other is seems overrided.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help.

Change this
`clsBuildingExeReport2.put("ClsBuildingExeReport", buildingExecRep_Detail_Main3);`

By
`clsBuildingExeReport2.accumulate("ClsBuildingExeReport", buildingExecRep_Detail_Main3);`

As when you use .put it just simply check if object with given key word(in your case it is `ClsBuildingExeReport`)is exist or not and if exist then it will replace but .accumulate add new object in that existing object.

Comment: `clsBuildingExeReport2` is a jsonObject but when i use accumulate it make clsBuildingExeReport2 to jsonArray https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb222585 @PATEL MEET

Comment: I think you have to make another object in pRequest in which add clsBuildingExeReport and for the rest do the same because you cannot append other JSONObject with same key word.